# Increase speed when comparing each row of a file to thousands of rows in a second file

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files. In the first file, I have 485 rows, in the second, 10700 rows. For every row in the first file, I compare two values for each row in the second file.

For example for the first row of the first file I compare it to the 10700 rows of the second file, and I do that for every row of the first file.

I tested with the first three rows of the first file, and it takes five minutes.

How could I increase the speed of the program?

I have an intel i7-6600U 2.6Ghz with 16Go ram.

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet

'Derniere ligne des fichiers
Dim LastRowPosa As Long
Dim LastRowBio As Long

'Cellules des fichiers
Dim rngPosaSejour As Range
Dim rngPosaDate As Range
Dim rngBioSejour As Range
Dim rngBioDate As Range

'item trouvé
Dim itemFound As Boolean

Dim cheminFichier As String

Dim datesEquals As Boolean
Dim sejourEquals As Boolean
Dim isAlbumine As Boolean

Dim tgo As String

'Variables incrémentielles
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
'Application Excel pour stocker le fichier BIO
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook

filePath= "C:\Users\me\Downloads\biologie.xls"

'New xl App
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Loading the two files
Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Get last row of each files
LastRowPosa = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
LastRowBio = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

tgo = "Albumine"

For i = 2 To 3
    Set rngPosaSejour = Application.Range("B" & i)
    Set rngPosaDate = Application.Range("P" & i)

    For j = 2 To LastRowBio
        If WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("I" & j) = tgo Then    
            Set rngBioSejour = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & j)
            Set rngBioDate = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("C" & j)
            sejourEquals = rngPosaSejour.Value = rngBioSejour.Value
            datesEquals = Format(rngBioDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") = Format(rngPosaDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
            isAlbumine = tgo = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("C" & j)
            If sejourEquals And datesEquals Then
                sht.Range("I" & i).Value = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("j" & j)
            End If    
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Without any code no one will be able to help.

Comment: VBA is relatively slow. Rewrite in C#, Java, or assembly.

Comment: Probably more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), Please make sure to include the code you are using though.

Comment: I shared the code

Comment: C#, Java has already been mentioned. I'll throw my hat in the ring and say that a language optimised for for comparing and cross referencing tabular data is of course SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using variant Array is faster.

```
Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet

'Derniere ligne des fichiers
Dim LastRowPosa As Long
Dim LastRowBio As Long

'Cellules des fichiers
Dim rngPosaSejour As Range
Dim rngPosaDate As Range
Dim rngBioSejour As Range
Dim rngBioDate As Range

'item trouve
Dim itemFound As Boolean

Dim cheminFichier As String

Dim datesEquals As Boolean
Dim sejourEquals As Boolean
Dim isAlbumine As Boolean

Dim tgo As String

'Variables incrementielles
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
'Application Excel pour stocker le fichier BIO
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim WBK As Excel.Workbook


Set sht = ActiveSheet '<~ set sht first

filePath = "C:\Users\me\Downloads\biologie.xls"

'New xl App
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Loading the two files

Set WBK = XL.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

Dim vDB As Variant, vData As Variant
Dim vR() As Variant

'Get last row of each files
'LastRowPosa = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
vDB = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'LastRowBio = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
vData = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 1), 1 To 1)
tgo = "Albumine"

For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1) '3
    'Set rngPosaSejour = Application.Range("B" & i)
    'Set rngPosaDate = Application.Range("P" & i)
    For j = 2 To UBound(vData, 1) 'LastRowBio
        'If WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("I" & j) = tgo Then
            If vData(j, 9) = tgo Then
            'Set rngBioSejour = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & j)
            'Set rngBioDate = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("C" & j)
                If vDB(i, 2) = vData(j, 1) And vDB(i, 16) = vData(j, 3) Then
                    'sejourEquals = rngPosaSejour.Value = rngBioSejour.Value
                    'datesEquals = Format(rngBioDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") = Format(rngPosaDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    'isAlbumine = tgo = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("C" & j)
                    'If sejourEquals And datesEquals Then
                    '    sht.Range("I" & i).Value = WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("j" & j)
                    'End If
                    vR(i, 9) = vData(j, 10)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
sht.Range("i1").Resize(UBound(vR, 1)) = vR
End Sub
```

Comment: Great  ! Thanks !

Comment: Letting the former code commented is nice to visualize the differences, both in terms of the statements that slowed down the execution and in terms of the gains in readability/code length. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your main loop with something like this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 2 To 3
    valPosaSejour = Application.Range("B" & i).Value2
    valPosaDate = Application.Range("P" & i).Value2

    For j = 2 To LastRowBio
        With WBK.Sheets("Sheet 1")
        If .Range("I" & j) = tgo Then
            valBioSejour = .Range("A" & j).Value2
            valBioDate = .Range("C" & j).Value2
            isAlbumine = tgo = .Range("C" & j).Value2
            If (valPosaSejour = valBioSejour) And (valBioDate = rngPosaDate) Then
                sht.Range("I" & i).Value = .Range("j" & j)
            End If
        End If
        End With
    Next j
Next i

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Instead of `Set`ting ranges for handling (that in each case you only use once) just load the values and compare.